# how to hide id in codeigniter url?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i want to hide id's in codeigniter like http://localhost/mysite/index.php/main/show_details/TABCGSHS0001

**i just want to hide 'TABCGSHS0001'** just show http://localhost/mysite/index.php/main/show_details/

Comment: You can not, if it's part of the url then you can't do much. Maybe use post request if hiding is that important.

Comment: You can't do that. One thing you can do is to encrypt that string when storing it into DB table in another column for example with let's say `md5('TABCGSHS0001')//here could probably be dynamic variable` and pull it out by that column with your model code. And that in case you don't want to show code presented in URL from question. However server or PHP need to know distinction between `details` to be able to fetch correct row.

Comment: You can not hide the parameter from URL with this method. If you do not want users to see the parameter, you have to use `POST` or `session`.